# Does python paths matter for IPython notebook?

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm new with IPython and I had this awkward problem with using a notebook:

When I try to use matplotlib

```
%matplotlib inline
```

I get this error:

> ImportError: /home/ipython/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libgfortran.so.3:
>   version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3)

But.. If I execute the code below **before**:

```
import sys
sys.path.reverse()
```

It works!

The question is: Does the order of python path matters? Do I need to install python dependencies in a correct order or set the python path to a correct order?

Thanks!

PS: I'm using jupyter server 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure paths do matter but the same way like for any other python program.

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Anyway, I think you should try first this [workaround](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/686#issuecomment-193835140), i.e. add to your `.bashrc`:

`export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3`

If it doesn't help you could try change `PYTHONPATH` in .bashrc. Anaconda adds itself there. So you could interchange it.

*Don't forget to reload `.bashrc` after changing with `source ~/.bashrc`*

Comment: Thanks for the help and for the tip!
It worked using this LD_PRELOAD.